# Доведение до ума функции смены иконки приложения

Tags: android, icon

Всем привет. Я реализовал у себя функцию смены иконки приложения. Чтобы не было мыслей о том, что я сделал что-то неправильно, расскажу как: создал 7 дополнительных разных иконок и к каждой иконке по классу. В манифесте насоздавал `activity-alias`-ы по такому шаблону:

```
<activity-alias
            android:name=".BLACK" <!-- один из 7 классов -->
            android:enabled="false"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_black_round" <!-- одна из 7 иконок -->
            android:targetActivity=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity-alias>
```

В коде сначала переключаю `enabled` на `true` у `activity-alias` с новой иконкой, затем выключаю остальные `activity-alias`:

```
private void changeAppIcon(AppIcon newIcon) {
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), newIcon.name),
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
        for (AppIcon icon : icons) {
            if (icon != newIcon) {
                pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                        new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), icon.name),
                            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
            }
        }
        appIconChangedListener.onAppIconChanged(newIcon);
}
```

В чем, собственно, суть вопроса. Спустя несколько секунд после смены иконки андроид закрывает приложение. Необходимо или ему это запретить делать и выполнять перезапуск самостоятельно, или после закрытия сразу же его обратно открывать. 
По-хорошему, нужно после смены иконки показывать информирующее об этом окно с кнопками "Перезапустить позже" и "Перезапустить сейчас".

Как эту функцию доделывали вы?

Comment: Не по теме, но ни разу не видел что бы можно было иконку менять)))) норм у вас заморочки))))

Comment: @Романыч ничего необычного на самом деле. меняется не сама иконка по сути а активный activity-alias. То есть для каждой иконки создан activity-alias а их активность меняется программно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в том, что основной активности тоже ставилась `enabled=false`. Я убрал строчку

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```

из тега основной активности и добавил новый алиас и класс для основной иконки. Вместо основной активности выключал этот новый алиас. Андроид перестал закрывать приложение после смены иконки.